# Wordpress adding highlight class to link using php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I tried doing this,

```
<li><a class="<?php if (is_page('index.php/client-2')) echo 'hightlight'; ?>" href="index.php/client-2">Client</a></li>
```

and that does not seem to work. Any suggestion? I don't want to use jquery and that would be my last resort. I already have highlight style in my css file. I just need to get php part working.

Comment: Wordpress is_page() function expects one of the following arguments: Page ID, Page Title or Page Slug. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`is_page`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) function expect a page ID, title or slug. Considering your page slug is actually `client-2` you should use the following instead:

```
<?php if (is_page('client-2')) echo 'highlight'; ?>
```

Remember that the page slug is just a normalized version of your page title, it doens't contain the parent page slug. So for a page with permalink `index/client-2` the slug is `client-2`.

And anyway `index.php/client-2` isn't a valid url.